# Regresar posicion de un arreglo, best practice

Tags: buenas-prácticas

Me he topado con dos maneras para regresar una posicion en un arreglo, en una funcion autoincremental y queria saber cual considerarian mejor y por que

1.-

```
public Object returnObject()
{
    objectIndex++;
    return objeto[objectIndex-1];
}
```

2.-

```
public Object returnObject()
{
     Object objetoNuevo = objeto[objectIndex]
     objectIndex++;
     return objetoNuevo ;
}
```

La primera opcion me gusta por que no crea una nueva instancia del objeto, utiliza menos lineas, pero tiene una manera extrana de manejar el indice,

la segunda opcion me parece mas simple, aunque utiliza una linea mas de codigo y genera una nueva instancia del objeto, lo cual no me parece del todo una buena practica tampoco.

en casos como este se deberia recurrir a la eficiencia del codigo o a la simplicidad  de este?

Comment: He utilizado la primera opción, ya que es mas sencillo y toma menos lineas de código.

Answer (score 0):

Des de mi punto de vista **ninguna de las dos parece buena**, explico el porqué:

1. **No se tiene en cuenta el posible desbordamiento de la array** de objetos. Una vez incrementado el objectIndex debe tenerse en cuenta si hemos pasado la capacidad del array.
2. **En ninguna de las dos se hace una instancia nueva de los objetos** del array. Object objetoNuevo = objeto[objectIndex] crea una referencia nueva pero no una nueva instancia. Para crear una nueva instancia habría que recurrir al concepto **deepcopy** (mirad esto [How do you make a deep copy of an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)
   )

Saludos

David